# Delphi memory stream to server

Tags: memorystream, delphi

I am working on creating a chat program. But for some reason my stream won't come through. Could someone check my code and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Client side:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  myStream : TMemoryStream;
  chat : String;
begin
  //Creating a stream
  chat := 'bladibla';
  myStream := TMemoryStream.Create();
  myStream.Size := Length(Chat);
  myStream.WriteBuffer(Pointer(Chat)^, Length(Chat));

  //Resetting the stream position
  myStream.Position := 0;

  //Sending the stream
  TcpClient1.Active := true;
  TcpClient1.SendStream(myStream);
  TcpClient1.Active := false;

  //Free the stream
  myStream.Free;
end;
```

Server Side:

```
procedure TForm1.TcpServer1Accept(Sender: TObject;
  ClientSocket: TCustomIpClient);
var
  chat : string;
begin
//Receives the message from the client
  ClientSocket.ReceiveBuf(Pointer(Chat)^,Length(Chat),0);

  memo1.Lines.Add(chat);
  memo1.Lines.Add('------');
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using D2009 or later, then when sending, you're cutting the data in half. Also, given you will ultimately be reading the data with `ReceiveBuf`, it would probably be sensible to prepend a length marker. Less substantively, you also don't need to set the memory stream's `Size` up front, and should wrap the stream usage in a try/finally block:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  myStream : TMemoryStream;
  chat : String;
  Len: Int32;
begin
  //Creating a stream
  chat := 'bladibla';
  myStream := TMemoryStream.Create();
  try
    Len := Length(Chat);
    myStream.WriteBuffer(Len, SizeOf(Len));
    myStream.WriteBuffer(Pointer(Chat)^, Len * SizeOf(Char));

    //Resetting the stream position
    myStream.Position := 0;

    //Sending the stream
    TcpClient1.Active := true;
    TcpClient1.SendStream(myStream);
    TcpClient1.Active := false;
  finally
    //Free the stream
    myStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

In the case of the receiving code, you haven't pre-allocated the `Chat` buffer. As such, `Length(Chat)` will be 0. Given my suggested code above, we can read off the length marker first:

```
procedure TForm1.TcpServer1Accept(Sender: TObject;
  ClientSocket: TCustomIpClient);
var
  chat : string;
  Len: Int32;
begin
  //Receives the message from the client
  ClientSocket.ReceiveBuf(Len, SizeOf(Len),0);
  SetLength(Chat, Len);
  ClientSocket.ReceiveBuf(Pointer(Chat)^,Len * SizeOf(Char),0);

  memo1.Lines.Add(chat);
  memo1.Lines.Add('------');
end;
```

Lastly... the components used in this code are deprecated, so it might be an idea to investigate Indy instead.

Comment: Another thing, but given the situation is a bit like defining a custom file type, it would probably be a good idea to avoid the generic 'string' type and use one with a specific encoding instead, just to make the nature of the data sent explicit in the code (that's why I used Int32 rather than Integer).

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. I am now gonna see why exactly :)

Comment: by "specific" do you meen something like shortstring or widetring?

Comment: @Eszee - I'd probably use `UTF8String`, assuming you are using a version of Delphi that has that type (reason being, UTF-8 is typically a much more compact Unicode encoding than UTF-16, which is what `WideString` uses). To convert from a normal string to a `UTF8String`, use the `UTF8Encode` function if using an old version of Delphi, or a cast if using D2009 or later - `MyUTF8Data := UTF8String(MySourceStr)`.

Comment: right, this would help with serverload. 

Thank you verry much